# Sort ignoring punctuation (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I am trying to sort an iOS UITableView object. I am currently using the following code:

```
// Sort terms alphabetically, ignoring case
[self.termsList sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

This sorts my list, whist ignoring case. However, it would be nice to ignore punctuation as well. For example:

```
c.a.t.
car
cat
```

should be sorted as follows:

```
car
c.a.t.
cat
```

(It doesn't actually matter which of the two cats (cat or c.a.t.) comes first, so long as they're sorted next to one another).

Is there a simple method to get around this? I presume the solution would involve extracting JUST the alphanumeric characters from the strings, then comparing those, then returning them back to their former states with the non-alphanumeric characters included again.

In point of fact, the only characters I truly care about are periods (.) but if there is a solution that covers all punctuation easily then it'd be useful to know.

Note: I asked this [exact same question of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396540/sort-ignoring-punctuation) a month ago. Now, I am creating the same solution in Objective-C. I wonder if there are any tricks available for the iOS API that make this easy...

**Edit**: I have tried using the following code to strip punctuation and populate another array which I sort (suggested by @tiguero). However, I don't know how to do the last step: to actually sort the first array according to the order of the second. Here is my code:

```
    NSMutableArray *arrayWithoutPunctuation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *item in arrayWithPunctuation)
    {
        // Replace hyphens/periods with spaces
        item = [item stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@" "]; // ...hyphens
        item = [item stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@" "]; // ...periods
        [arrayWithoutPunctuation addObject:item];
    }
    [arrayWithoutPunctuation sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

This provides 'arrayWithoutPunctuation' which is sorted, but of course **doesn't contain the punctuation**. This is no good, since, although it is now sorted nicely, it no longer contains punctuation which is crucial to the array in the first place. What I need to do is sort 'arrayWithPunctuation' according to the order of 'arrayWithoutPunctuation'... Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just use a custom comparator.

Comment: As yet I haven't been able to implement it. I'll accept once I can get it to work

Comment: I am sorry I think I confused you a bit you just need my first suggestion - did u try it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a comparison block on an `NSArray` and your code will look like the following:

```
NSArray* yourStringList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"c.a.t.", @"car", @"cat", nil];
NSArray* yourStringSorted = [yourStringList sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b){
        NSString* as = (NSString*)a;
        NSString* bs = (NSString*)b;

        NSCharacterSet *unwantedChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\\.:',"];
        //Remove unwanted chars
        as = [[as componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: unwantedChars] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
        bs = [[as componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: unwantedChars] componentsJoinedByString: @""];

        // make the case insensitive comparison btw your two strings
        return [as caseInsensitiveCompare: bs];
    }];
```

This might not be the most efficient code actually one other option would be to iterate on your array first and remove all unwanted chars and use a `selector` with the `caseInsensitiveCompare` method:

```
 NSString* yourStringSorted = [yourStringList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a number of days now. I'm trying to implement your second suggestion (I couldn't manage to implement the first); please see my edit to my post!

Comment: @CaptainProg: tiguero's first suggestion will accomplish what you want.

Comment: As @iMoses has done above, this doesn't work for my setup. I have no idea why, but strings with a full-stop remain ABOVE those without, regardless of which solution I use... This is definitely caused by this code, as it only happens after I try a sort algorithm (of any type). So sorting (of some kind) is happening. Will try to dig deeper, but the bounty is likely to expire before I find out why

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work; this code still causes splitting into separate words. For example, the array [cat, c.a.t and car] is organised in the order [c.a.t, car, cat]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit cleaner, and a bit more efficient:

```
NSArray* strings = @[@".....c",@"a.",@"a",@"b",@"b...",@"a..,"];
NSArray* sorted_strings = [strings sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString* a = [obj1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];
    NSString* b = [obj2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];
    return [a caseInsensitiveCompare:b];
}];
```

For real efficiency, I'd write a compare method that ignores punctuation, so that no memory allocations would be needed just to compare.

Comment: This code, like the first code by Tiguero, still sorts my terms with hyphens and full stops above those without... Will try to work out how, but it looks like the bounty will expire first

Comment: I have checked it and it works fine for me, use this array, @[@".....c",@"a",@"a.", @"b",@"b...",@"a..,"]; it gives, (
    a,
    "a.",
    "a..,",
    b,
    "b...",
    ".....c"
)

Comment: @CaptainProg, this code (and @tiguero's) works just fine. Either your question is misleading or you've missed something else. Unlike your sorting method - it does not replace punctuation with spaces so that "c.a.t." and "cat" are equal, again, unlike your code that will give the two a different weight.

Comment: I have unselected this answer as this code still causes splitting into separate words. For example, the array [cat, c.a.t and car] is organised in the order [c.a.t, car, cat]

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to group each string into a custom object with *two* properties

- the original string
- the string without punctuation

...and then sort the objects based on the string without punctuation.

Objective C has some handy ways to do that.
So let's say we have two strings in this object:

```
NSString *myString;
NSString *modified;
```

First, add your custom objects to an array

```
NSMutableArray *myStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myStrings addObject: ...];
```

Then, sort the array by the *modified* variable using the handy NSSortDescriptor.

```
//You can specify the variable name to sort by
//Sorting is done according to the locale using localizedStandardCompare
NSSortDescriptor *mySortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"modified" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
[myStrings sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ mySortDescriptor ]];
```

*Voila! Your objects (and strings) are sorted.*  [For more info on NSSortDescriptor...](http://nshipster.com/nssortdescriptor/)