# how to sort a object array according to particular parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a class having different attributes like place name ,place distance,user name, .i am storing this class object inside a array .i want to sort this object array according to distance .how could i do .please suggest with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"placeDistance" ascending:TRUE];
[your array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]]
```

Comment: my pleasure @Ranjan Sahu

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* array...
NSArray* sorted_array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    YourClass* a = (YourClass*)obj1;
    YourClass* b = (YourClass*)obj2;
    /*
    return NSComparisonResult based on a property comparison here,
    for example, return [a.distance compare:b.distance] if distance is an NSNumber
    */
}];
```

Much like [Sort ignoring punctuation (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058389/sort-ignoring-punctuation-objective-c/13249229)